# Select row from multiple table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get data from multiple tables (all tables are identical)

```
Select column1,column2 From table1,table2
```

Is it a correct way to get this in MYSQL. (I am passing table names dynamically in the query)

Comment: You cannot pass in table names dynamically. They must be known to the database in advance.

Comment: Your query is probably syntactically correct, assuming 1. both `table1` and `table2` exist, 2. there is one column named `column1` in either `table1` or `table2`, 3. there is one column named `column2` in either `table1` or `table2`, and 4. `column1` or `column2` do not exist in *both* tables. Now, what are you trying to obtain from this query and/or are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you need is this one :

```
SELECT a.column1, b.column2
FROM table1 AS a, table2 AS b
```

`AS` give your table an alias you can directly use in your request.

Answer (score 0):

Like:

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2 
FROM table1, table2
```

By fully-qualifying the column using the table, you won't run into conflicts when columns have the same names in the tables. As [zessx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098948/select-row-from-multiple-table/11098991#11098991) states in his answer, an alternate way to do this is to alias the tables, which can make the query simpler with long table names / schema names.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
 SELECT column1, column2
 FROM table1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT column1, column2
 FROM table2
```

But you cannot pass in table names dynamically. They must be known to the database in advance (so you need to construct the SQL in your program first).